# Can anybody explain this

Tags: kotlin

everyone. Please, can anybody help me to inteprete this code below?

```
fun getBoard(row: Int , col: Int): Int {
    return _draughBoard[row][col]
}
```

Comment: "Can anybody explain this" is an unclear title that's hard to search for -- it could apply to just about any problem. What specifically do you not understand about the code? It's a function that reads a cell value from a 2-d array of ints by row and column.

Comment: I agree with @ggorlen, it's not clear for us which part exactly you're having trouble with. Also, could you please share the declaration of `_draughBoard`? This is the most important part to be able to answer your question properly

Answer (score 2):

Since your example is small enough, let's break it down completely:

- `fun` is a keyword to introduce a function declaration
- `getBoard` is the name of the function declared here
- the `()` delimit the list of arguments (parameters) of the function
- `row` and `col` are the names of the 2 arguments of the function
- `: Int` after each argument means that they are of type `Int` (which represents integers)
- `: Int` after the `)` is the return type of the function. It means the result of the function is an integer as well
- `{}` delimit the body of the function (the implementation)
- `return` is a keyword that allows to exit the function by returning the value provided right after it
- `_draughBoard[row][col]` is an expression describing the value that will be returned

  - `_draughBoard` is most likely a list of lists of integers (or array of arrays of integers) that has been declared elsewhere in the same class or globally
  - `[]` is the syntax for the `get` operator, it allows to access an element in a list, or array, or any structure defining the `get` operator. You need to pass an integer between the brackets, and that integer acts as an index to find an element in the list/array/structure.
  - `_draughtBoard[row]` is the value of the element of `_draughBoard` at index `row`. It is most likely a list or array of integers.
  - `_draughBoard[row][col]` is the value of the element of `_draughBoard[row]` located at index `col`, which is an integer (the one that we return from the function)